# sticky session configuration css 11503

Tags: networking, load-balancing, sticky-sessions

I have two jboss instances behind a cisco css 11503 for load balance. In each of this instances, I have two applications. One of them, needs sticky sessions to be enabled, the other does not. Is it possible to configure this on this cisco css model? Based for example on the url. Like www.mydomain.com/appA to have sticky sessions enabled, and www.mydomain.com/appB to not have? If it is possible, how can I do it?

Thanks

Kelly

Answer (score 1):

I believe that sticky sessions are defined with the `advance-balance` statement. If you don't specify `advanced-balance` for a content, CSS won't use stickyness. Like this:

```
content content-appA
    add service server1
    add service server2
    url "/appA/*"
    advanced-balance arrowpoint-cookie
    protocol tcp
    port 80
    vip address 1.2.3.4
    active

content content-appB
    add service server1
    add service server2
    url "/appB/*"
    protocol tcp
    port 80
    vip address 1.2.3.4
    active
```